# how many ways are there to order the word LYCANTHROPIES when C isn't next to A, A isn't next to N and N isn't next to T

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

a. total number of ways to order 13 letters in a word: **13!**

b. Number of ways for CA/AC: 2*12!

Number of ways for AN/NA: 2*12!

Number of ways for NT/TN: 2*12!

**Total: 3*2*12!**

c. Number of ways for CAN/NAC: 2*11!

Number of ways for ANT/TNA: 2*11!

**Total: 2*2*11!**

d. Number of ways for CANT/TNAC: **2*10!**

using the inclusion–exclusion principle I got:
13! -(3*2*12!) + (2*2*11!)-(2*10!). $$-$$
the textbook solution is: 13! -(3*2*12!) + (2*2*11!) **+(2*2*11!)**-(2*10!).
I dont know what I am missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In part c, did you mean CAN/NAC?

Comment: It seems that you have forgot in part C all the options where _C is next to A_ and _N is next to T_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overlooked the case in which there are two disjoint pairs of prohibited adjacent letters.

**Strategy:**  There are $13$ distinct letters in LYCANTHROPIES, so there are $13!$ arrangements of its letters.  From these, we must subtract those arrangements in which there are one or more prohibited pairs.

*A prohibited pair of adjacent letters*:  You correctly calculated that there are $3 \cdot 12!2!$ such arrangements in part b of your work.

*Two prohibited pairs of adjacent letters*:  This can occur in two ways.

1. Two overlapping pairs of adjacent letters:  This means that you have three consecutive letters, namely CAN, NAC, ANT, TNA.  Assuming you meant NAC rather than NA$\color{red}{\text{T}}$, you correctly calculated that there are $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 11!$ such arrangements in part c of your work.
2. Two disjoint pairs of adjacent letters:  This is the case you overlooked.

The two disjoint pairs are CA/AC and NT/TN.  We have $13$ letters in total, so there are $11$ objects to arrange, the block containing A and C, the block containing N and T, and the other nine letters.  The objects can be arranged in $11!$ ways.  In each block, there are $2!$ ways to arrange the letters within the block.   Hence, there are $11!2!2!$ arrangements of this type.  This is the missing term.

*Three pairs of prohibited adjacent letters*:  This means that you have four consecutive letters, namely CANT, TNAC.  You correctly calculated that there are $2 \cdot 10!$ such arrangements in part d of your work.

Hence, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of admissible arrangements is 
$$13! - 3 \cdot 12!2! + 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 11! + 11!2!2! - 2 \cdot 10!$$

Answer (score 1):

In part C of your calculation, you have forgot to include/exclude the option of: *C next to A* and *N next to T*

For this option you'll have $2 * 2 * 11!$ ways, which alongside with your final answer matches what the textbook states.